# PolymerJS: Firing tap event on paper-tabs

Tags: javascript, polymer

I would like to do something like this

```
window.menuTab.$.paper_tabs.children[0].click()
```

or

```
window.menuTab.$.paper_tabs.children[0].tap
```

where [0] is the first tab. Is theres any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to navigate to other tab

Comment: You should be using for example `selected="0"` instead, on your `core-paper-tabs`.

Comment: I can use as answered below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround to change tab by using this :

```
window.menuTab.$.paper_tabs.selectIndex(2)
```

where 2 is tab number 3 because it started from 0.